# Ubuntu / Bash recognising "export PATH=$PATH:~/..." but not "export PATH=$PATH:/home/..."

Tags: bash, bashrc, execute-command, .profile

So I've been using ubuntu since 09.04 but have limited experience with sys admin.  I now want to get into web development and as part of installing the Play Framework, I had to add the activator path to `$PATH`.

After plenty of research it still wasn't working, I had tried adding

`export PATH=$PATH:/home/Play/...`

to both .bashrc and .profile and although both scripts were adding the directory to $PATH, as seen using

`$echo $PATH`

I was still seeing "command not found" when trying to run activator commands

More by luck than anything else I amended the script to read

`export PATH=$PATH:~/Play/...`

and lo and behold, it worked.

**Questions:**

- Why would the script not recognise "`/home/`" but recognise "`~/`" (my home drive is on a separate partition if that explains it) and could this be indicative of a bigger problem with my installation? *[Edit: Solved! as pointed out in comments below, this is because ~/ points to /home/username/ and not just /home/]*
- I have left this script in .bashrc, is this the best place for it as including it in `.profile` seemed to do the same thing?

Comment: Your home directory is probably not `/home/`, it's probably something like `/home/sibow/`. Do this to see for yourself: `echo ~` and `ls /home`

Comment: @glennjackman make that an answer, you're most likely right.

Comment: @glennjackman: If you don't make it an answer, I will!  :P  ;-)

Comment: Go for it. It's only the first part anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your home directory is probably not `/home/`, it's probably something like `/home/sibow/`. Do this to see for yourself: `echo ~` and `ls /home`

–  [glenn jackman](https://askubuntu.com/users/10127/glenn-jackman) [Jan 10 '15 at 14:42](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571709/ubuntu-bash-recognising-export-path-path-but-not-export-path-path#comment787910_571709)